# Xunit Test/NET.Core/ Theory based on InlineData that takes values of my Fields from my Model, while Testing the Controller

Tags: c#, controller, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit

This is the Model, that contains two fields
Field1, and Field2

```
public class DemoViewModel
{
    public string Field1{ get; set; }
    public string Field2{ get; set; }
}
```

Below we have the controller

```
public class SearchDemoController: BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult SearchDemo(DemoViewModel model)
    {


        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Field1))
            throw new NotImplementedException("Error page - wrong Field1 chosen");

        var Field1= DatabaseHandler<Field1>.Get(a => a.IsoName.ToLower().Contains(model.Field1));

    }
}
```

My Failed Xunit Test: or what i think it should happen, but i lack the knowledge to proper assess:
is it possible to pass fields from the viewmodel as inlinedata for the Theory?
ex..pass model.Field1 as null and as empty for the test in InlineData.
As well, i have a problem in how to test if Field1 is being handled by database handler. Any Advice?

```
[Theory]
[InlineData] -Field1 Value 1
[InlineData] -Field1 Value 2
[InlineData] -Field1 Value 3
    public void SearchDemo_DbHandlerContainsModelField1_WhenField1IsContained()
    {
        //Arrange

        var model = new DemoViewModel();
        model.Field1= "Value1"; //i wish somehow to add the values in InlineData
        var language = DatabaseHandler<Field1>.Get(a => a.IsoName.ToLower().Contains(model.Language));

        //Act

        //Assert
        Assert.NotNull(model.Field1);
        Assert.Equal("Value1",model.Field1);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify `Field1` value as a parameter :

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("Value1")]
[InlineData("Value2")]
[InlineData("Value3")]
[InlineData(null)]
public void SearchDemo_DbHandlerContainsModelField1_WhenField1IsContained(string field1)
{
    //Arrange
    var model = new DemoViewModel();
    model.Field1 = field1;

    //Your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much...one small question..how do i pass a null value?

Comment: I edited my answer to include null case. If this answer helped, please upvote and mark as an answer.

Comment: Thank you once more, upvoted and definitely marked as an answer:D